# Import JSON files into SQL Server using OPENJSON only, no permission to use bulk load statement

Tags: json, sql-server

I wish to import JSON data into SQL Server. I have done some research, using bulk function (perhaps I am wrong) to import JSON file and then using other function to further sort or parse these data.

I found out that I have no permission to use bulk load statement. Another possible way is to use `OPENJSON`, but it seems that the `OPENJSON` function can only read existing data, for example prestored in some table.

Can anyone show me how to import JSON files using `openjson` or any other methods? And if it is not possible, how can I retrieve the permission?

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: Microsoft sql server 2016. Thanks

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57275552/sql-server-t-sql-import-multiple-json-files-in-a-loop/57284537#57284537) may help to find a solution to your problem. But you need an appropriate [permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#permissions).

Comment: Thanks Zhorov. I am wondering if there are any ways to import json file into sql as plain text without the use of OPENROWSET.