# Recursively importing JSON Files in SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

Is there a possibility to import multiple directorys of JSON files in SQL Server 2019 with a non privileged user (xp_cmdshell not available) and not using SSIS? Just with plain SQL in SSMS.

Comment: This is possible. The first thing you would want to do is declare a variable with the folder path of the location of the json files. The second thing would be to create a temporary table with the name and extension of the json files (excluding the part of the path that is parameterised). Then you would want to loop through the parameter\filename (from temporary table) with an OpenJSON command and wrap it in an insert into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with [OPENROWSET(BULK)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/import-json-documents-into-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) and [WHILE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/while-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) cicle but it is not the best way to do it.

In the following post you can try a example of this.

[SQL Server T-SQL - import multiple JSON files in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57275552/sql-server-t-sql-import-multiple-json-files-in-a-loop)

I recommend you to use [SSIS Foreach Loop Container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lesson-2-2-adding-and-configuring-the-foreach-loop-container?view=sql-server-ver15) instead of OPENROWSET(BULK) for best performances
and resource consumption.